# Вывод на экран русских символов php

Tags: php

День добрый! Не могу понять почему при выводе на экран всей строки отображается как должно, а при переборе �? Подскажите в чем дело...

**UPD**

```
$string = strtolower($str); 
var_dump($string[1]); 
var_dump($string);
```

Comment: В `charset`. Он должен быть такой же как и кодировка вашей страницы (если есть БД, то тоже такая же кодировка должна быть при подключении)

Answer (score 2):

В `PHP` для корректной работы с многобайтовыми строками используются отдельные функции:

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.mbstring.php

Answer (score 2):

Так происходит потому, что вы используете многобайтовую кодировку (UTF-8). В частности, русские буквы занимают два байта/

Возьмем, например, слово "Вася". В UTF8 оно будет занимать не 4 байта, как вы наверное ожидали, а 8. Вот они

```
В     а     с     я
D0 92 D0 B0 D1 81 D1 8F
```

Соответственно, когда вы печатаете эти байты по одному, то вывод получается не тем, который вы ожидали. И учитывая, что 7-битный ASCII заканчивается на коде `7F`, все, что выше печатается как неизвестный символ.

Собственно, как отметили в соседнем ответе - надо использовать специальные функции для работы с многобайтовыми кодировками. В вашем случае подойдет [mb_split](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-split.php)

**UPD**

```
$string = "Вася"; 
// Выводит "неизвестный" символ с кодом 92
var_dump($string[1]);         
// Выводит непрерывную последовательность байт 
// D0 92 D0 B0 D1 81 D1 8F, которая интерпретируется как "Вася"
var_dump($string);
```

Comment: вопрос в том что при выводе целого слова все срабатывает..а если обратиться к отдельному символу кодировка не работает...

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, как вы выводите посимвольно (вот тупо копипастой, а не написанный заново специально для вопроса). Там есть нюансы. В браузер выводите или в консоль?

Comment: $string = strtolower($str);
    var_dump($string[1]);
    var_dump($string);

Comment: вывод в браузер..это обычная строка и обычное обращение к элементу...но целую строку выводит норм, а отдельный элемент - нет

Comment: Добавил разбор вашего случая в ответ

Comment: и какое решение?

Comment: Вам в двух ответах написали решение - для работы с многобайтовыми кодировками используйте функции, для них предназначенные.

Comment: ok.....спасибо...

Comment: А почему если обратиться к отдельному символу кодировка то не работает? Ведь если все слово целиком выводить все срабатывает.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов Потому, что var_dump помимо, собственно, своего аргумента, выводит до черта дополнительной информации вокруг него.